# Aiogram телеграм бот, не находит переменную, определенная в global

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

```
from aiogram import executor, Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher.storage import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from config import TOKENG
from random import randint

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(TOKENG)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
    InlineKeyboardButton(randint(0, 100))
])


class ProfileState(StatesGroup):

    num_one = State()
    num_two = State()
    attempt = State()
    result = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Привет! Если хочешь поиграть в игру "Угадай число", то пропиши команду /guess')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['guess'])
async def guess_num(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Напиши число, от которого будет загадываться рандомное число')
    await ProfileState.num_one.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=ProfileState.num_one)
async def num_first(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global number_1
    number_1 = int(message.text)

    await message.answer('Отправь число, до которого будет загадываться рандомное число')
    await ProfileState.next()


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit, state=ProfileState.num_one)
async def fisrt_num_check(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Вы ввели не число!')


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not message.text.isdigit, state=ProfileState.num_two)
async def fisrt_num_check(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Вы ввели не число!')


@dp.message_handler(state=ProfileState.attempt)
async def num_first(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global number
    number = int(message.text)        # Кол-во попыток

    await message.answer('Введите число попыток')
    await ProfileState.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=ProfileState.num_two)
async def num_second(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global rnum
    number_2 = int(message.text)
    await message.answer(f'Я загадал число от {number_1}, до {number_2}, попробуй угадать загаданное число, у вас есть {number} попытки[ок]')
    rnum = randint(number_1, number_2)
    await ProfileState.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=ProfileState.result)
async def input_result(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    while True:
        if rnum < int(message.text):
            return await message.answer('Меньше')
        elif rnum > int(message.text):
            return await message.answer('Больше')
        elif rnum == int(message.text):
            return await message.reply('Вы отгадали загаданное число!')
        elif number == 10:
            await message.answer(f'Вы потратили все попытки! Верное число: {rnum}')
            break
        else:
            await message.answer('Ошибка: вы ввели не число!')
        number += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Вот ошибка, выходит после того как пользователь ввел второе число:

```
> Task exception was never retrieved
>     future: <Task finished name='Task-18' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407>
> exception=NameError("name 'number' is not defined")>
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py",
> line 415, in _process_polling_updates
>         for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py",
> line 235, in process_updates
>         return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py",
> line 116, in notify
>         response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py",
> line 256, in process_update
>         return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
>       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py",
> line 116, in notify
>         response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
>       File "D:\pythonProject\telebot\guess number.py", line 71, in num_second
>         await message.answer(f'Я загадал число от {number_1}, до {number_2}, попробуй угадать загаданное число, у вас есть {number}
> попытки[ок]')
>     NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все переменные надо указать в начале кода

```
number = 0
number_1 = 0
number_2 = 0
rnum = 0
```

и в каждой функции надо взять все нужные переменные из глобального списка переменных

```
@dp.message_handler(state=ProfileState.num_two)
async def num_second(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global rnum, number, number_1, number_2 # вот здесь надо писать все переменные которые используется в данной функции
    number_2 = int(message.text)
    await message.answer(f'Я загадал число от {number_1}, до {number_2}, попробуй угадать загаданное число, у вас есть {number} попытки[ок]')
    rnum = randint(number_1, number_2)
    await ProfileState.next()
```

и последняя функция вообще неправильна, надо вот так:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=ProfileState.result)
async def input_result(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global rnum, number, number_1, number_2
    if msg.text.isdigit(): # проверяем число ли сообщение
        if rnum < int(message.text):
            await message.answer('Меньше')
        elif rnum > int(message.text):
            await message.answer('Больше')
        elif rnum == int(message.text):
            await message.reply('Вы отгадали загаданное число!')
            rnum = 0
            number = 0
            number_1 = 0
            number_2 = 0 # анулирываем все переменные
            await state.finish() # завершаем fsm так как юзер угадал число и игра закончилась
        elif number == 10:
            await message.answer(f'Вы потратили все попытки! Верное число: {rnum}')
            rnum = 0
            number = 0
            number_1 = 0
            number_2 = 0 # анулирываем все переменные
            await state.finish() # завершаем fsm так как юзер потратили все попытки и игра закончилась
        number += 1
    else:
        await message.answer('Ошибка: вы ввели не число!')
```

и ещё две вещи

1. зачем вы делаете всё на глобальных переменах если есть state (если не знаете погуглите как пользоваться fsm state)
2. настоятельно рекомендую называть файлы без пробела:
   `guess number.py` -> `guess_number.py`